# Union where and whereIn queries into single request

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, builder

I have two requests

```
DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')->where('updated_at', '=', $now)->get();
```

and

```
DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')->whereIn('key', $keysArr)->get();
```

I want to unite them into one request but I'm afraid that if I do it like

```
DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')
    -> where('updated_at', '=', $now)
    -> whereIn('key', $keysArr)
    -> get();
```

the `whereIn` will filter on the `where` result.
Is that so?

Comment: Do you mean `->where('updated_at', '=', $now)->orWhereIn('key', $keysArr)`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes, I want both results and to unique them

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: orWhere is most "eloquent" here but know for future reference there is an actual "union()" call that can be made on a query object to union with another like this $queryObject->union($queryObject2);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then you want to do like this

```
DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')
    ->whereIn('key', $keysArr)
    ->orWhere('updated_at', '=', $now)
    ->get();
```

You can use 'orWhere' clause if you want 'or' result between both of your condition.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')
-> where('updated_at', '=', $now)
-> orWhere(function($q) use($keysArr){
     $q->whereIn('key', $keysArr);
})
-> get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To specifically "union" the two queries:

```
$queryOne = DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')->where('updated_at', '=', $now);
$queryTwo = DB::table('myTable')->select('id', 'name')->whereIn('key', $keysArr);

$unifiedQueryResults = $queryOne->union($queryTwo)->get();
```

I actually like the orWhere solution offered by Jitendra for this specific case but unions are needed in other cases.